# How to return several data on success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to return two different data on success in ajax, for example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url_action,
   type:'POST',
   data: dataToSend,
   success:function(results)
   {
      $(".photosLive").html(results);
   }
```

});

In results, there are two pieces of information: **Title** and **Image**.
Then I need to put title in another div `.titleLive` and put image in `.photosLive` (but it's already OK)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. The best way to do this is to have whatever URL you're requesting return the result as JSON. If, however, it has to return HTML, you could do this:

```
...
success: function(results) {
    // select the image and title from wherever it may be in the HTML returned
    var response = $(results),
        title = response.find('#title').text(),
        image = response.find('img').attr('src');

    // Do whatever with your info.
}
```

*Edit:* Example with JSON return:

The page returning the title and image information:

```
{"title":"My Title","image":"http://mydomain.com/image.png"}
```

And your success callback (you don't have to set new variables for the response, I'm just doing it to illustrate):

```
success: function(results) {
    var title = results.title,
        image = results.image;

    // Do whatever with your info.
}
```

Comment: How can do this with JSON ? Your answer is coding in jQuery no ?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely jQuery. If you have JSON coming back from the request, it's super simple. `results.title` and `results.image` would be immediately available for you to work with.

Comment: Ok ! But how can return my `results` in JSON ?

Comment: @Steffi: whatever URL you are calling will have to format the results as JSON. jQuery will auto-detect whether the response coming from the server is HTML or JSON.

Comment: Okay ! Great ! So I'll try this !

Comment: But... I have a question. How the function can know my informations "title" and "image" ? Because these are divs ? Or why ?

Comment: No divs involved. Let's say that you're making an AJAX request to some url, let's say `/images`. If you were to browse to that URL in your browser, it would simply return `{"title":"Some title","image":"http://mydomain.com/someimage.png"}`. When you make an AJAX request to that URL using jQuery, the result in the `success` callback will be a Javascript object. If you were to then `alert(results.title);`, you would get the title returned from `/images`. JSON is simply a way of formatting information.

Comment: So. I added `datatype : "json"`. And in my url, I do :  `$responseVar = array(
                    'title'=>'Bacon',
                    'image'=>'bababa.png'
                    );` And I `echo json_encode($responseVar);` Good or not ?

Comment: So actually, I need to put my informations in an array, Isn't it ?

Comment: Oh! You probably have more than one result being returned. Yep. You do need to create an array of the results. You definitely have the right idea, though. Keep at it and see if you can get it working.

Comment: When I try to display in alert my information title : `alert(results.title);` I have : **undefined** in alert. However in Firebug, the response is : `{"title":"Tatoun"}`. What's the problem ?

Comment: I need to add this : `results = jQuery.parseJSON(results);` then `alert(results.title);` After, IT WORKS ! Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 3):

You could return a JSON object containing two fields, title and photo which you can then parse and insert into your DOM

JSON syntax is basically Javascript object syntax, take a look at:

http://www.json.org/js.html

There are JSON generators from Objects for almost any server side language

JSON example: Say your server generates the string I assigned to the var json (instead of html) so you receive it as response of your ajax call into your success method

```
var json = '{title:"A new title", photo:"path/to/pic"}'

var result = jQuery.parseJSON( json ); 


$('.titleLive').text(result.title);
$('.photosLive').attribute(src, result.photo);
```

To return your response in JSON is just plain text with correct format, for example in your server side something like:

```
setResponse("{title:\"A new title\", photo:\"path/to/pic\"}");
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depend on the data type you return (Json/XML/etc.).
Suppose you return plain text: `title:lorup ipsum,image:foobar.png`:
In the `success` function:

`var returnedData = results;`

`var title = returnedData.split(",")[0].replace('title:','');`

`var image= returnedData.split(",")[1].replace('image:','');`

`$(".titleLive").html(title );`

`$(".photosLive").html(image);`

By the way, this not clean. As I mentioned it, the best way is to use structured data.

Regards.